# Why my react native iOS app crashes on splash screen with Thread 1: signal SIGABRT?

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, splash-screen

React Native iOS app crashes on launch , when splash screen renders and it gets stuck there with an error in main.m file

I tried, cleaning build and deleting derived data, pod update and pod install as well.

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));   *Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
  }
}
```

also from debugger I can see :

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```